# Login flow from mobile app on web server with Facebook Oauth

Tags: facebook, authentication, spring-security, spring-social

I have a web application built with Spring and spring security that allows user to register ether via Facebbok or creating an account, in both cases an web app account is created. So the 2 registering methods are the following::

- Registering directly on the web app: the username and password are stored in the db.
- Registering via facebook: the user logins into facebook (Outh), the web app retrieve the data from facebook to fill the registration form. The web app prompt the user to create the webapp account. In my database I store web app user and facebook data (access token etc..), so that the second time I try to login I can match the facebook account with the web app account (I use spring social).

Now I'm creating a rest service for the mobile app and it requires authentication. I use the basic http auth to access the web services.

My question now is how to Log in a user in my web application using spring security?

What I thought was:

- Mobile app logs into facebook and retrieve the access_token (no contact with the web application server yet)
- Mobile app sends access token to the web app
- Web app checks if the access token is valid ether with db or directly with facebook
- In case is valid the access token, the app sends back to the mobile app the username and the password (could be encrypted with a private key algorithm)
- Once receive the web app user and password the user is authenticated and this information are stored on the mobile and used for http auth.

Do you think this flow is secure? do you have other ideas?

Thank you in advance